Неверная обработка переноса строк и слэша в sql-звпросе
(1064, 'You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ' title= "Создать объявление?", description= "Марка: \n' at line 1')
sql = f'SELECT `id`, `user_id`, `title`, `description`, `type`, `price`, `server`, `seller`, `user_tag`, `number`, `exchange`, `files` FROM `ads` WHERE `user_id`= {user_id}, `title`= "{title}", `description`= "{description}", `type`= "{type}", `price`= {price}, `server`= "{server}", `seller`= "{seller}", `user_tag`= "{user_tag}", `number`= {number}, `exchange`= {exchange}, `files`= "{files}"'

Дело в том что в description передается длинный текст с переносами строк.
Конкретно:
"car":"""`
Марка: 
Модель:
Гос. цена: 
Цена продажи в гос.:
Цвет: 
Прошивки: 
Внешний тюнинг: 
Тюнинг света: 
Тюнинг подвески: 
Доп. информация:`"""

и из-за того что присутствует перенос строки и в конце строки стоит \ питон думает что я хочу убрать ковычку "\
a = "hello, \"world\""

Как мне обыграть данную ситуацию?

питон, что, не умеет передавать параметры в запрос как это делается во всех других языках? Есть запрос с плейсхолдерами и есть параметры. Они в СУБД передаются отдельно друг от друга, что избавляет от дичи вызванной прямой подстановкой переменных в тело запроса, а заодно обнуляет риски sql инъекций,  дает бенефиты использования подготовленных выражений в виде кэширования плана выполнения запроса при многократном последовательном выполнении этого самого запроса.

леее забыл внатуре
